# Usage of cmake flags in Relase and Debug mode

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, release

I am trying to adapt a C++ library for my own usage and it contains the following lines in it's root CMakeLists.txt

```
set(BUILD_TYPE_RELEASE TRUE)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -no-pie -march=native -ggdb -Wall \
-Wextra -Wcast-align -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 \
-Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Woverloaded-virtual \
-Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Werror")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O3  -ggdb -std=gnu99 -I.")
```

Based on my understanding so far, it's build type is set to Release and certain optimization flags and Warnings are set to the C++ and C compilers. I have the following questions

1. Debugging is usually done without any optimizations (`-O0`), so if I
   compile the code in debug mode by passing `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`,
   will the optimization flag of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` automatically set to 0
   instead of 3?
2. Is it relevant to have the gdb and warnings set to the C and CXX
   Flags, if the build type is set to Release mode?
3. I am assuming these flags are relevant only when debugging with command line because while debugging with an IDE like VSCode, I would be asked to specify a debugger and it usually creates configurations automatically. Is this assumption correct?

I may have to debug it in the future so I would like to have a clear understanding on how the release and debug modes play along with these flags. I am pretty new to CMake and debugging so, sorry if my questions are wrong in some sense. I would very much appreciate if someone link some resources for understanding the usage of these flags to this thread, I am having a hard time finding these in the cmake documentation.

I am running the code on linux and my cmake version is 3.5.1

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` represents flags **common** for all build types. If you want to set flags for Release builds only, then assign them to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` variable. BTW, by building the project with `make VERBOSE=1` you may inspect **actual** flags which are passed to the compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: For flags related with error-checking using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is OK. As opposite, checking `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in `if` clause is a bad approach as it won't work in multi-configuration generators.

Comment: If `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are common for both build types, does this mean the compiler automatically assigns flags for each build types? For example, will `-O3` will be set to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `-ggdb` will be set to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` depending on the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`? and thank you for the `make VERBOSE=1` tip, tried it and I think it'll be very useful for me. @Tsyvarev

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "automatically". If you perform Debug build, then CMake passes to C++ compiler sum of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` variables, nothing more. And compiler just works with that flags. It is true that CMake provides reasonable **defaults** for variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` (and for other variables), so they could work even without manual modifications. But whether you use default variable settings or modify them, CMake simply passes these variables to the compiler without postprocessing.